# React Native list of active applications on the phone and blocking the launch of another application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, activiti

How to get a list of running applications on a phone in a react native or expo? How can I force the launch of another of an application? Is this even possible? I saw there are parental control applications with similar functionality ...

Comment: You can get the list of installed applications in the android device by installing below npm module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-installed-apps  and whereas force launch of another application, you have to do it from native side

Comment: You can't get a list of applications on iOS. You can't block an application on iOS.