# React Native - possible for one app to view/query the existing apps on a users device?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am building an app in React Native, and was wondering if I could check to see if another app is installed on the user's device. Is it possible,  or is there a 'permission' that I could prompt user for in order to have access to this?.
Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556716/react-native-list-of-active-applications-on-the-phone-and-blocking-the-launch-of

Comment: bummer on ios. thanks!